# help undersand what happened with my ecryptfs password

Tags: password, ecryptfs

A week ago I forgot my session password. Changing it a week before holidays wasn't a good idea...
I changed it using Ubuntu in recovery mode but connecting the session didn't work. Using an other account, I understood my home was encrypted. My only solution to recover my data is to remember my password.

With a Python script I wrote a list of the 50 000 possible passwords. I run that codes :

```
    #!/bin/sh 
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do;
    ./ecryptfs_pass.sh $line 2>&1 | tee -a results.txt
    done < "$1"
```

where ecryptfs_pass.sh is a expect script starting with :

```
    spawn ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/username/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
    expect "*assphrase*"
    send -- "$argv\r"
```

and caching if an error is raised.

As you can imagine, I was glad to have a match. So I got my old_password. So I changed the password of my login session to old_password and try to open it. However, the response still the same. Moreover, the program I wrote doesn't catch old_password anymore.

I was excited to find my password and to be close to the end but I found myself in fact more confused. Can anybody could explain what happened and what can I do to solve that situation and get my data back ?

PS: to be complete, I think I run the program with a wrong path : */home/test_user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase* where test_user is something I created to reproduce the situation with a password I know but I'm sure what I got is the old_password and not the dummy ones I used for test_user these last days.